# Quality control triage review question seems unfair

Tags: discussion

I was given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11066663) in the Triage review queue. The post *has* an actual question, though very poor grammar and the question definitely needs to be expanded. I marked it as "Requires Editing" to correct the grammar and links, with the intent to then leave a comment to the user to explain more information in the question. The post turned out to be a test post, and I failed the test (locking me out of review for 2 days, which is fine, I'm a team player, I'll wait patiently)

Once the results came back it was clear why the post was deleted. It appears that this was a user that was posting multiple questions and so on and so forth, so was probably a duplicate/abuse and therefore deleted. This makes sense. However, at the time, how was I supposed to know that that was going on. It just seemed to be a real question with poor grammar.

Should this question be removed from the quality control review questions?

Comment: So, the community cannot fix the post so as to make it answerable in your estimate? Sounds unsalvageable...

Comment: If the grammar was corrected then the post would be answerable (low quality) but answerable. A comment should be left for the OP to give more details about the situation, but in essence this isn't much different then a "Why my code not work?" [paste code block here] question. I am in **complete agreement** that the post is low quality, but not *unanswerable*

Comment: I've lifted the review suspension...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you very much for that.

Comment: Well, one look at the post made me retreat, so my comment just went off what you wrote instead. Sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: It's a terrible question.  And it was probably chosen as an audit because the person asking apparently was abusing the site with this question from multiple accounts.  Note the comment "Now from a differen account?" on the question.  The question got extra special downvoting because of this, and that helped put it into a category from which audits are drawn.  Now, there's probably no way you could have known this fact when reviewing the question, which means the audit is bad.  Audits should be clear, not borderline. You're too generous trying to salvage questions like this, btw.